# Nhibernate -- Excuting some simple HQL

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, hql

I have map the entities in .hmb.xml and define attribute for all entity in classes.

I have some basic accomplishment and get all the record using below code.

```
public List<DevelopmentStep> getDevelopmentSteps()
   {
       List<DevelopmentStep> developmentStep;
       developmentStep = Repository.FindAll<DevelopmentStep>(new OrderBy("Id", Order.Asc));
       return developmentStep;
   }
```

I have check from net that we can write HQL, Now the problem is how to execute this HQL like..

```
string hql = "From DevelopmentSteps d inner join table2 t2 d.id=t2.Id where d.id=IDValue";
```

What additional Classes or other thing I need to add to execute this kind of HQL?

Please help me ---- Thanks

Comment: Getting a session is basic for NHibernate, you can't do anything without a session. Take a look at the first chapter of the manual: "Quickstart", e.g. "Playing with Cats": http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#quickstart-playingwithcats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To write dynamic queries, I recommend using the Criteria API. This is dynamic, because you have a single query for several different types and you also want to set the ordering dynamically.
- The queries are always object oriented. You don't need to join by foreign keys, you just navigate through the class model. There also no "tables" in the queries, but entities.
- Getting (single) instances by ID should always be done using `session.Get` (or `session.Load`). Only then NHibernate can also take it directly from the cache without database roundtrip, it it had already been loaded.

for instance:

```
public IList<T> GetAll<T>(string orderBy)
{
    return session.CreateCriteria(typeof(T))
      .AddOrder(Order.Asc(orderBy))
      .List<T>();
}
```

Comment: Criteria API, is this .dll I have to add? whats session here and need to pass here?

Comment: The criteria is included in Nhibernate.dll. Take a look at the manual. http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-criteria

Comment: you provide me very good link, I am facing problem, how can create session object to get CreateCriteria method. I am unable to get in my class, can you plz tell me what to do get session.CreateCriteria().......Thanks

Comment: Can you plz look into this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681078/nhibernate-getting-single-column-from-other-table